# Truncate timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like into a stored procedure, truncate timestamp input values at the top hour or at the lower hour.

For example, if my input values are `2020-02-12 06:56:00` and `2020-02-12 07:14:00`, I would like to transforme it in `2020-02-12 06:00:00` and `2020-02-12 08:00:00`

Is a cast function can work?

Comment: can you show some sample data and expected result to illustrate what you want here ?

Comment: I just edited my question @Squirrel :)

Comment: How do you decide to round down `06:56` to `06:00` and round up `07:14` to `08:00` ?

Comment: I have to do a calculation that need to have rounded values of timestamp @Squirrel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the new datetimes from the parts that you want of your original datetimes.

```
declare @start datetime = '2020-02-12 06:56:00'
declare @end datetime = '2020-02-12 07:14:00'

select @start as OriginalStart,
       @end as OriginalEnd,
       datetimefromparts(year(@start), month(@start), day(@start), datepart(hour, @start), 0, 0, 0) as TruncatedStart,
       dateadd(hour, 1, datetimefromparts(year(@end), month(@end), day(@end), datepart(hour, @end), 0, 0, 0)) as TruncatedEnd
```

The first truncation of the interval is the lower hour, and the second one adds an additional hour so it returns the higher hour.

PS: If what you want is to round to the nearest hour, then you can add 30 minutes and truncate :

```
declare @date datetime = '2020-02-12 06:56:00'

set @date = dateadd(minute, 30, @date)

select datetimefromparts(year(@date), month(@date), day(@date), datepart(hour, @date), 0, 0, 0) as NearestHour
```

or in a single step (using Lepetit's shortcut for truncation) :

```
declare @date datetime = '2020-02-12 06:56:00'

select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(minute, 30, @date)), 0) AS NearestHour
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit of arithmetic calculation, convert to hours with decimal and use `floor()` and `ceiling()` to perform the round up / down

first it find the time different with `00:00:00` in terms of second. `convert(date, date_col)` convert the datetime to date, so effectively it is `00:00:00`

```
datediff(second, convert(date, date_col), date_col)
```

then you divide by `60 x 60 = 3600` seconds. Gives you fraction of hours

then you use `floor()` or `ceiling()` to perform the rounding

and lastly you add that back to the date (`convert(date, date_col)`)

Final query

```
select  *,
        RoundDown   = convert(datetime, convert(date, date_col)) 
        + dateadd(hour, floor(datediff(second, convert(date, date_col), date_col) / (3600.0)), 0),
        RoundUp     = convert(datetime, convert(date, date_col))
        + dateadd(hour, ceiling(datediff(second, convert(date, date_col), date_col) / (3600.0)), 0)

from    (
            values 
            ('2020-02-12 06:56:00'),
            ('2020-02-12 07:14:00')
        ) d (date_col)

/*
2020-02-12 06:56:00 2020-02-12 06:00:00 2020-02-12 07:00:00
2020-02-12 07:14:00 2020-02-12 07:00:00 2020-02-12 08:00:00
*/
```

EDIT : a much simpler query below

find the different in `minute` divide by `60.0` minutes to get different in terms of hour (with decimal places) and then apply `floor` or `ceiling`. Finally add that result back

```
select  getdate() as Now, 
        dateadd(hour, floor(datediff(minute, 0, getdate()) / 60.0), 0) as RoundDown,
        dateadd(hour, ceiling(datediff(minute, 0, getdate()) / 60.0), 0) as RoundUp
```

Comment: I tried your query but had this error ```Date and datetime data types are incompatible in added additions..```

Comment: edited the query. Later version of `SQL Server` does not likes that.

Comment: Added a much simpler query

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler solution:

```
declare @start datetime = '2020-02-12 06:56:00' 
declare @end datetime = '2020-02-12 07:14:00'    

select @start as OriginalStart,
       @end as OriginalEnd,
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @start), 0) as TruncatedStart, 
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(hour, 1, @end)), 0) as TruncatedEnd
```

In both cases the function substracts the hour part from the original timestamp. For the TruncatedEnd, one hour is added, so that the result is the subsequent hour.